# Execute a list of queries and store result in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute the queries resulted from the variable @roles and store the results in the table @table :

```
    DECLARE @roles NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @roles=' '
    DECLARE @table TABLE
   (
    Label NVARCHAR(MAX)
   )

    select @roles=@roles+
    'Select '+isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')+' from '+er.SchemaName+'.'+er.TableName+' where '
 +kcu.COLUMN_NAME +'='+er1.ValueId


         from [Function].[Role] er 
        left outer join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on 
            tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
        left outer join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_Role er1 ON er.EntityRoleId = er1.RoleId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee e ON er1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    where e.EmployeeId=54 AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY'

    INSERT INTO @table
  EXEC sp_executesql @roles;
```

The result of @roles is different query like below : 
[image]

I am getting :

> ( 0 rows affected )

Comment: can you post some input data sample and table structure of your tables used in query.

Comment: Do the queries return any rows? Have you verified @roles actually contains those queries? The behavior of aggregate string concatenation (e.g. `@roles=@roles+...`) is undefined so you should instead use `STRING_AGG` (SQL 2017 and later) or `XML PATH` in earlier versions as detailed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax/207380#207380).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you want to store your result of `sp_executesql` in your table, the syntax is following

```
    INSERT INTO @table ( Label  )
  EXEC sp_executesql @roles;
```